# Another word for talk of the town?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The discussion-topic/chatter/buzz that has everyone interested or excited but is also constrained to a certain location.

Examples:

> After winning the super bowl, the Eagles were *the talk of the town* in Philly.
>   The new statue in the park is *the talk of the town*.

A single word preferably, but not necessarily.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: @TrevorD sorry about that. I added some detail. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I've formatted your Q. for clarity. But **note** I've also changed "but necessarily" to "but *not* necessarily", which, I assume, is what you intended.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there *is* nothing else that encompasses the whole meaning of  *local cause celebre* as well as *talk of the town*. (Not even *local cause celebre*. That's an alternative, but I don't see it as being any better. It's certainly not much shorter.)

Comment: I would say "on everyone's lips", but I am pretty sure that would probably get a lot of snarky comments...

Answer (score -1):

As in:

*After winning the super bowl, the Eagles were the Philly **conversation piece.***

and

> 1958   J. K. Galbraith Affluent Society    Perhaps the bank
>   rate..derived prestige from its position as a Victorian **conversation
>   piece**.

From the OED:

> **conversation piece**  n.  a subject for conversation; something to talk about;  (c) a piece of conversation; a dialogue